# Visit each node in a graph a certain number of times

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, graph-theory, graph-traversal

There are exactly n nodes and n - 1 edges in a graph. Each node has a value assigned to it, which is the number of times it must be visited. Starting from a node, return whether or not there is a way to visit each node the specified number of times. [Note: the start node should not be counted as visited initially.] 

Example:

```
A: Visit 1 times
B: Visit 2 times
C: Visit 1 times
D: Visit 1 times
A <-> B
B <-> C
B <-> D
Starting from B

Result: true
(Go from B to A, A to B, B to C, C to B, B to D)
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: There's an algorithm for this sort of problem: (1) think of a solution that might work, (2) code and test it (3) ask a question about your solution here.

Comment: If this is not a tree, then the problem becomes finding a Hamiltonian path if the visitation number is 1. Finding a Hamiltonian path is NP complete, so I guess this problem is also NP complete, at least in the form presented here.

Comment: @jrook Ah, but that's the trick, isn't it? A graph with exactly n nodes and n-1 edges? That's a tree, isn't it.

Comment: @beaker, not necessarily. The question does not specify if the graph is connected or not. There could be cycles in the graph while some nodes are left hanging with a degree of 0.

Comment: @jrook But that would be an easy answer unless the disconnected nodes had a count of 0.

Comment: @beaker A simple word *connected* would fix this problem. I agree that the case for trees are way more interesting and quite possibly the purpose of the problem.

Comment: @jrook Yes, that would certainly make it more precise.